# x tick labels in print outside the box when rotated 90 degrees

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, xticks

I'm using a Pandas dataframe to plot a bar graph.  The x axis is made up of dates, and I need a lot of x-axis so I rotate them 90 degrees so that they're somewhat readable. However, they're printing outside the box. And even if I try using the figsize, the size of the graph is changed, but still the x ticks are printed outside.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = pd.Series(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02' ,'2023-01-03'])
df['# total dictated'] = pd.Series([45, 32, 22])

ax = df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='# total dictated', rot=90, 
                 title='Total dictations per day', legend=False, fontsize=10, xlabel='')
ax.figure.savefig('volume.png')
```

And this is the image it gives. Notice how the dates are completely unreadable since they're printed outside the box.

[image generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDyhN.png)

Comment: And this is related to MATLAB how? Please use the proper tags, so the people interested and knowledgeable about the topic see it.

Comment: I thought that all these plots were generated by the matlab API, no?

Comment: Matplotlib’s design was heavily influenced by MATLAB, originally. But it’s it’s own thing, and differs from MATLAB in many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bbox_inches = 'tight' in savefig to get it to calculate a tight bounding box. Otherwise the it will use the default savefig.bbox.

i.e. change the last line to

```
ax.figure.savefig('volume.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```